# Why does my code print "built-in method" and some hex numbers?

Tags: python, built-in

Here is my Key function:

```py
def Key(message, decision):
    key = input("Input the key which will be used to encode the message.\n".lower)
    n = 0
    for i in range(len(key)):
        if 64 < ord(key[n]) < 91:
            raise ValueError(key[n], "is a capital letter!")
        else:
            n = n+1
    Keycode(decision, message, key)
```

When I call it and input the message and press enter it comes up with:

> built-in method lower of str object at 0x0150E0D0

What's wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like you forgot the parentheses after `somestring.lower` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Key` contains this problematic line:

```
key = input("Now, input the key which will be used to encode the message.\n".lower)
```

which passes as input to `input` the `lower` method of a string, when you (presumably) want to pass the string and then apply `lower` to what `input` returns.

Answer (score 17):

After `.upper` or `.lower` there has to be a closed pair of parentheses. You can put custom arguments in them but if you just want to capitalize the input leave them empty.

Example:

```
user=(input("Enter a letter:")).upper()
```

This will change case to upper.

Comment: this is what I get for using ruby for too long. I just spent 30 minutes trying to debug this.

Comment: thanks. I was using value.title instead of value.title()

Answer (score 3):

You need to use closed pair of parenthesis after lower

```
key = input("Input the key which will be used to encode the message.\n".lower())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
key = input("Input the key which will be used to encode the message.\n".lower)
```

Because lower function is missing parenthesis, put parenthesis after function call. so syntax would be like
`key = input("Input the key which will be used to encode the message.\n".lower())`

Answer (score 0):

.lower() method is a method of the str class.
.lower() converts the string to lowercase. in order To call the lower() method you need to write the name of the method(.lower or .upper), followed by parentheses().

Answer (score -4):

Try saving your work in your work space. If you're using the Python prompt to check your results, use the `exit()` command and open a Python prompt again. Then try calling the previous functions as you were doing earlier on.