# Bot translates string to memory location

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I just started working on my first ever bot and wanted to make a command called "***!gender***". You put your gender behind it and then the **bot gives the role to you**. Unfortunately it somehow sets the gender variable to **some memory** location instead of the **name** you put in and I dont know how to fix it. Please help ^^

For example it outputs:

*<built-in method lower of str object at 0x7fc35adfc230>*

Instead of:

Male

***Code:***

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from replit import db

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"Successfully logged in as {client.user}")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  msg = message.content

  if msg.startswith("!gender"):
    gender = msg.split(" ")[1].lower
    if gender != "male" and gender != "female":
      await message.channel.send(f"Thats a invalid gender. (Male / Female) You selected gender: {gender}")
    if gender == "male":
      role = get(message.server.roles, name="Male")
      await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
      await message.channel.send("Added \"Male\" role to your account!")
      
    if gender == "female":
      role = get(message.server.roles, name="Female")
      await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
      await message.channel.send("Added \"Female\" role to your account!")
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321701/why-does-my-code-print-built-in-method-and-some-hex-numbers) post

Comment: Unrelated tip: try using `discord.ext.commands` for a better way to use commands. It's much easier to accept arguments and input validate them this way. (Also I believe it should be `member.add_roles(role...)` not with the bot)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `msg.split(" ")[1].lower` to `gender = msg.split(" ")[1].lower()` as reminded by [TheFungusAmongUs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16177247/thefungusamongus).